# Ctypes Multiple Function callback

Tags: python, python-2.7, ctypes

I am facing an issue with registering multiple callbacks with ctypes to interact with my C library.

I am using two different types of `CFUNCTYPE` objects to register two distinct callbacks at the same time with different API's, but my library gets the same function pointer in both of the API's, and consequently one callback is called twice.

I am trying to do something like below:

```
callback_type_1 = ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(ctypes.c_int, 
                                   ctypes.c_int, 
                                   ctypes.c_void_p, 
                                   ctypes.c_int,
                                   ctypes.c_void_p, 
                                   ctypes.c_void_p, 
                                   ctypes.c_int)

callback_type_2 = ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(None, 
                                   ctypes.c_int, 
                                   ctypes.c_void_p, 
                                   ctypes.c_int, 
                                   ctypes.c_int,
                                   ctypes.c_void_p, 
                                   ctypes.c_int, 
                                   ctypes.c_void_p)

classify_callback_ptr_1 = callback_type_1(callback_1)
_lib.api_1(ctypes.c_int(handle),  classify_callback_ptr_1)

classify_callback_ptr_2 = callback_type_2(callback_2) 
_lib.api_2(ctypes.c_int(handle), classify_callback_ptr_2)
```

If I print the function pointer inside api_1 and api_2, I get the same pointer value.

Does ctypes just allow one callback to be registered at a time ? Or is there anything else that I'm missing.

Comment: could it be that you are printing `handle` instead of the callbacks?

Comment: You can check with `ctypes.cast(classify_callback_ptr_1, ctypes.c_void_p)`, and so on. Apparently there's something else that you're missing.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Sebstain, no I m not printing the handle. I am printing the pointer.

Eryksun, casting seems to have overcome the issues but it non-deterministic as it will crash the library a few times.

Comment: I didn't mean for you to use the `cast`, just to check that the addresses for the callbacks are unique. Based on the code you've shown, that's definitely true. Each callback has its own `CThunkObject` and points at a bit of executable memory that basically (hand waving) jumps to a function that converts the arguments, calls `PyObject_CallObject(callable, arglist)`, and sets the result.

Comment: Thanks Erksun. I was not keeping the reference of classify callbacks in python and python garbage collection was clearing the function references making new callback to reuse the same memory location. Saving those references solved the issue.